# Adding multiple scopes to a Compute Engine VM instance on Google Cloud not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm trying to create a Compute Engine VM instance `sample` in Google Cloud that has an associated startup script `startup_script.sh`. On startup, I would like to have access to files that I have stored in a Cloud Source Repository. As such, in this script, I clone a repository using

```
gcloud source repos clone <repo name> --project=<project name>
```

Additionally, `startup_script.sh` also runs commands such as

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json --iam-account <account>
```

which creates `.json` credentials, and

```
EXTERNAL_IP = $(gcloud compute instances describe sample --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)' --zone=us-central1-a)
```

to get the external IP of the VM within the VM. To run these commands without any errors, I found that I need partial or full access to multiple Cloud API access scopes.

If I manually edit the scopes of the VM after I've already created it to allow for this and restart it, `startup_script.sh` runs fine, i.e. I can see the results of each command completing successfully. However, I would like to assign these scopes upon creation of the VM and not have to manually edit scopes after the fact. I found in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) that in order to do this, I can run

```
gcloud compute instances create sample --image-family=ubuntu-1804-lts --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud --metadata-from-file=startup-script=startup_script.sh --zone=us-central1-a --scopes=[cloud-platform, cloud-source-repos, default]
```

When I run this command in the Cloud Shell, however, I can either only add one scope at a time, i.e. `--scopes=cloud_platform`, or if I try to enter multiple scopes as shown in the command above, I get

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) unrecognized arguments:
  cloud-source-repos,
  default]
```

Adding multiple scopes as the documentation suggests doesn't seem to work. I get a similar error when use the scope's URI instead of it's alias.

Any obvious reasons as to why this may be happening? I feel this may have to do with the service account (or lack thereof) associated with the `sample` VM, but I'm not entirely familiar with this.

BONUS: Ideally I would like to run the VM creation cloud shell command in a `cloudbuild.yaml` file, which I have as

```
steps:
   - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
   entrypoint: gcloud
   args: ['compute', 'instances', 'create', 'sample', '--image-family=ubuntu-1804-lts', '--image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud', '--metadata-from-file=startup-script=startup_sample.sh', '--zone=us-central1-a', '--scopes=[cloud-platform, cloud-source-repos, default]']
```

I can submit the build using

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

Are there any issues with the way I've setup this `cloudbuild.yaml`?

Comment: Does your service account have the proper roles? Also, can you try to remove default after cloud repos and see if that changes anything? It states its an argument error, therefore the syntax is wrong but it does look fine to me

Comment: Advice. Compute Engine Scopes limit permissions assigned to the service account. Scopes do not increase/add permissions. Use the "cloud-platform" scope and manage the permissions via roles assigned to the project for the service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Adding multiple scopes as the documentation suggests doesn't seem to work

Please use the this command with `--scopes=cloud-platform,cloud-source-reposCreated` and not `--scopes=[cloud-platform, cloud-source-repos, default]`:

```
gcloud compute instances create sample --image-family=ubuntu-1804-lts --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud  --zone=us-central1-a --scopes=cloud-platform,cloud-source-reposCreated 

[https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/wave25-vladoi/zones/us-central1-a/instances/sample].
NAME    ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS
sample  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.128.0.17  35.238.166.75  RUNNING
```

Also consider @John Hanley comment.